# Factorisation and hence ...

Tags: arithmetic

Factorise $2x^2 + 8x + 6$ completely . Hence express 286 as the product of three prime factors .

Workings -
$2x^2 + 8x + 6
= 2(x^2 + 4x + 3)
=2(x+3)(x+1)$

How do I use my answer above to express 286 as the product of three prime factors ?

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: How do you normally write $286$?  What is the meaning of the location of each number?  $286 = 2\cdot 10^2 + 8\cdot 10^1+6\cdot 10^0=$ two hundreds plus eight tens plus six ones.

Comment: Hint; the question wants you to have $286$ equal to the expression.

Comment: $2(x+1)(x+3)=286\iff(x+1)(x+3)=143\iff(x+1)(x+3)=11\cdot13\iff(x+1)(x+3)=(10+1)(10+3)\iff{x}=10$, hence $286=2(10+1)(10+3)=2\cdot11\cdot13$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right- $2x^2+8x+6=2(x+3)(x+1)$

Now, $2x^2+8x+6=286$ will give you $x=10$

So, $286=2(x+3)(x+1)=2\times 13 \times 11$

The prime factors are $2,13,11$